# When I try to add more than 4 images to the layout, the app crashes

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am making a simple table layout and displaying two images per row. When I add four images that fits in a single screen than its working correct but when I add more rows and other images the app crashes and says the app has stopped working. I have yet not started touching the mainActivity.class file. Just making a layout is giving me this error!

Here is the xml code:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <TableRow>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:src="@drawable/img1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/img2"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:src="@drawable/img3"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/img4"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:src="@drawable/img5"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/img6"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:src="@drawable/img7"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/img8"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:src="@drawable/img9"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/img10"/>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Error Log:

> 06-21 13:42:16.190    1542-1551/android.process.acore E/StrictMode﹕ A
>   resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See
>   java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
>   java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
>             at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
>             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.

Comment: Please share your logcat log? I guess the error is Out Of Memory Exception?

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar Please have a look at error log.

Comment: @ThuongLe Please have a look at error log.

Comment: Show your `MainActivity` code.

Comment: @Clairvoyant I have already mentioned about that I have not yet touched my MainActivity code. It is same as when we start the new blank activity.

Comment: Do you have only one activity??? Because you xml looks fine. If you have any other activity then check in your manifest that whether `MainActivity` is your first activity.

Comment: @Clairvoyant Yes I have only one activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use libraries for that purpose because dealing with memory is hard task when adding images to your application and you don't want to do it by yourself.

Thankfully, Picasso Library is very good for that and you should better read about it and use it in your application.

Here is a link to the library:

[square/picassor . GitHub](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Comment: I am trying to make a simple app for practice in which user will get 10 images on the screen and he can choose any of them to make it as his wallpaper. It will be appreciated if you will guide me How should I start and what resources should I use?

Comment: @AltafHusainNeva: that's exactly this library do, it will load your images without causing OutOfMemory Exception. 
Are you use Android Studio or Eclipse ?

Comment: I use Android Studio. Anyways can I use this library to download images from the url and load it in my app?

Comment: @AltafHusainNeva: Yes, and it's very easy you will only use one line of code to download and show image. See this link hopefully you will understand how to do it.http://square.github.io/picasso/